# Kiam oni rajtas uzi la vorton "ŝofori"?

Tags: word-usage

Laŭ PIV

> ŝoforo. Profesia kondukisto de aŭto, kamiono ks.
>
> ŝofori. Labori kiel ŝoforo

Laŭ Reta Vortaro

> ŝofori (tr)
> TRA Profesie kondukadi veturilon: *oni devas atenti la vojon, kiam oni ŝoforas, ĉu ne?*

Kio estas "profesie konduki"?

Se oni kondukas aŭton por irigi ebriajn amikojn hejmen, ĉu oni rajtas diri ke oni *ŝoforis* la aŭton?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En la praktiko oni ofte uzas "ŝofor-" kiel verban radikon, do

> "ŝofori" = stiri aŭton
>
> "ŝoforanto" = stiranto de aŭto

Tiam la signifo de la vorto "ŝoforo" (profesia aŭtostiristo) fariĝas neregula, do oni povas kontraŭi tian uzon de "ŝofori". Tamen oni ofte trovas ĝin kaj povus argumenti, ke fakte la signifo ŝanĝiĝis, ĉar kontraste al la Zamenhofa tempo la stirado de aŭto ne plu estas afero por profesiulo.

Se vi volas uzi la lingvon laŭfundamente uzu "stiri" kaj "stiranto".